# Cakephp joining tables via find option not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to join a Users table to my curent hasMany Through table which has Interest and User model id's.

Below is the find query with options:

```
$params = array(
                    'fields' => array('*', 'COUNT(DISTINCT(InterestsUser.interest_id)) as interest_count'),
                    'limit' => 15,
                    'recursive' => -1,
                    'offset' => $offset,
                    'conditions' => array('InterestsUser.interest_id' => $conditions),
                    'group' => array('InterestsUser.user_id'),
                    'order' => array('interest_count DESC', 'InterestsUser.user_id ASC', 'InterestsUser.interest_id ASC'),
                        'joins' => array(
                            array('table' => 'users',
                                'alias' => 'User',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'User.id' => 'InterestsUser.user_id',
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );

            $results = $this->InterestsUser->find('all', $params);
```

This returns InterestsUser table fine but does not return any values for Users table. It only returns field names.

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE:**
OK, above is generating below SQL which I got from Cake's datasources sql log:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT(InterestsUser.interest_id)) as interest_count 
FROM `interests_users` AS `InterestsUser` 
LEFT JOIN users AS `User` ON (`User`.`id` = 'InterestsUser.user_id')  
WHERE `InterestsUser`.`interest_id` IN (3, 2, 1)  
GROUP BY `InterestsUser`.`user_id`  
ORDER BY `interest_count` DESC, `InterestsUser`.`user_id` ASC, `InterestsUser`.`interest_id` ASC  
LIMIT 15
```

Why is users table values returning NULL only for all fields?

**UPDATE:**

OK I tried below but this is working fine...What am I missing here!!??

```
SELECT * , COUNT( DISTINCT (
interests_users.interest_id
) ) AS interest_count
FROM interests_users
LEFT JOIN users ON ( users.id = interests_users.user_id ) 
WHERE interests_users.interest_id
IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) 
GROUP BY interests_users.user_id
ORDER BY interest_count DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: ok I found the issue. It's this InterestsUser.user_id field!!! Apparently I need to take out ' to get this working! But why is this happening? How can I take this off as it is added by Cake's datasource? I really do not want to use custom sql query...

Comment: Have you tried `conditions => array('User.id = InterestsUser.user_id')` ?

Comment: Please look above at the initial Cake options query. It already has that value under joins array!

Comment: oK I think this is MySQL's bug. Why do we have to take out ' on the either foreign key or primary key of joining tables to get this working? This is really strange...

Comment: It's the difference between `array('User.id' => 'InterestsUser.user_id')` and `array('User.id = InterestsUser.user_id')` The docs have it like the latter [http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables).

Comment: OK you are right! Please leave it in the answer so I can tick you as answer to this question. Thank you so much Doug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array syntax for join conditions should be like the following

```
array('User.id = InterestsUser.user_id')
```

as opposed to `array('User.id' => 'InterestsUser.user_id')`. For more, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables.